# Proving the Identity: $\frac{x^{n}-1}{x+1} = x^{n-1} - x^{n-2} + \cdots - 1$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand why the following equation holds true:

$$\frac{x^{n}-1}{x+1} = x^{n-1} - x^{n-2} + \cdots - 1$$

where $n$ is even.

Using the long division, I was able to recover the first few terms on the right hand side, so I am convinced that it is true. But I would like to find an alternative argument. I think it might have something to do with power series, but I could not find the appropriate argument.

Comment: Write out the usual formula for $1+(-x)+(-x)^2+\cdots+ (-x)^{n-1}$.

Comment: This is a duplicate, for example answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483575/question-on-geometrical-proof-of-geometric-series), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474708/basic-geometric-series) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810508/relationship-between-taylor-series-and-geometric-series).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship between taylor series and geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810508/relationship-between-taylor-series-and-geometric-series)

Comment: No it does not answer my question

Comment: just multiply both sides by the divisor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the geometric series formula. It's easy to find a proof of this online if you're not already familiar with it.
$$1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots + r^{n-2} + r^{n-1} = \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}$$
Substitute $r = -x$, keeping in mind that since $n$ is even we have $r^n = x^n$.
$$1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \cdots + x^{n-2} - x^{n-1} = \frac{1-x^n}{1 + x}$$
Multiply both sides by $-1$ and you get your desired equality.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates. Details on the reasons behind this request can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Given that it wasn't known to be a duplicate at the time of me posting this, I'm a bit confused why you're speaking to me like this as if I were knowledgably answering a duplicate. (Sidenote: it doesn't appear to be a duplicate as far as I can tell after reviewing your links.)

Comment: No offense was intended, I'm convinced that you wanted to help and I only wanted to inform you about the guidelines, same as I was informed about them [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4618434/1096797).

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with the inner-outer multlication proof. Let's take $n=4$:
$$(x^3-x^2+x-1)\require{enclose}(x+1)=x^4+\enclose{horizontalstrike}{x^3-x^3}-\enclose{horizontalstrike}
{x^2+x^2}+\enclose{horizontalstrike}
{x-x}-1=x^4-1
$$
True! So is it true for any $n$?

Let's take $n=5:$
$$x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1...$$
I see... This is not in the given form. So, $n$ must be even. Then inner-outer multtplication proves the given identity, as in the proof of the well-known identity $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1$.